# Cant validate Role.py model in Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Im trying to write simple application with this project structure:

```
website (root directory)  
..mainws (its app)  
....migrations(not filled)  
....usermodels  
......__init__.py  
......Role.py  
....__init__.py  
....admin.py  
....models.py  
....test.py  
....views.py  
..website(directory for project)  
..manage.py
```

And after making project, I created mainws app, when wrote for Role table. Also added in models.py (directory mainws):

```
from usermodels import Role
```

But using in terminal "manage.py sqlall mainws" giving for me big stacktrace (mainws app added at the and of INSTALLED_APPS). How can I fix this trouble?

Role.py contains code:

```
from django.db import models


class Role(models.Model):
    role_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    def GetRoleName(self):
        return self.role_name

    def SetRoleName(self, new_role_name):
        if self.role_name != new_role_name:
            self.role_name = new_role_name
```

Stacktrace:

```
=> python manage.py sqlall mainws
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/savicvalera/code/lab8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/savicvalera/code/lab8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/savicvalera/code/lab8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Users/savicvalera/code/lab8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/savicvalera/code/lab8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 449, in handle
    app_output = self.handle_app_config(app_config, **options)
  File "/Users/savicvalera/code/lab8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/sqlall.py", line 25, in handle_app_config
    statements = sql_all(app_config, self.style, connection)
  File "/Users/savicvalera/code/lab8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 174, in sql_all
    check_for_migrations(app_config, connection)
  File "/Users/savicvalera/code/lab8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 18, in check_for_migrations
    loader = MigrationLoader(connection)
  File "/Users/savicvalera/code/lab8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 48, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/Users/savicvalera/code/lab8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 179, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/Users/savicvalera/code/lab8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 59, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "/Users/savicvalera/code/lab8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 53, in ensure_schema
    editor.create_model(self.Migration)
  File "/Users/savicvalera/code/lab8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 263, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/savicvalera/code/lab8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 99, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/savicvalera/code/lab8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 81, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/savicvalera/code/lab8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/savicvalera/code/lab8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/savicvalera/code/lab8/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: no schema has been selected to create in
```

Comment: What is the point of those setter and getter methods on Role? That is not how you do things in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following changes :

1) Rename your usermodels folder to models folder(for simplicity).

2) In the `__init__.py` file of models folder, import the Role model using `from . import Role`.

3) leave the models.py file(of the outer directory) blank.

So ultimately you will have the following structure

```
website (root directory)  
..mainws (its app)  
....migrations(not filled)  
....models  
......__init__.py  
......Role.py  
....__init__.py  
....admin.py  
....models.py  
....test.py  
....views.py  
..website(directory for project)  
..manage.py
```

Then run the sqlall command.It should work!